# hbase export to flat file

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm pretty new to hadoop...

I have a bunch of data in an hbase table that I need to export (with some minor transformation) out to a single flat file. To do this, I am building a mapreduce job that scans the table and maps the data to a Text type with TextOutputFormat.

Something like this:

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("tablename",      // input table
    scan,             // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
    MyMapper.class,   // mapper class
    Text.class,             // mapper output key
    Text.class,             // mapper output value
    job);

job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/tmp/mydirectory"));
```

And my mapper:

```
private static class MyMapper extends TableMapper<Text, Text> {
    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result result, Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
        String json = new String(result.getValue("cf".getBytes(), "qualifier".getBytes()));

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

        //...builds the line up

        Text k = new Text("filename-20141205.txt");
        Text lineText = new Text(line.toString());
        context.write(k, lineText);
    }
}
```

However, what I get out is a single file with the keys and the data in a part-r-00000 file. I think I need a reducer to finish the job, but I'm not sure what it looks like.

Would the identity reducer work? Is there a better way to go about this problem other than TextOutputFormat?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
private static class MyOutputFormat<K, V> extends TextOutputFormat<K, V>{
    @Override
    public Path getDefaultWorkFile(TaskAttemptContext context, String extension) throws IOException {
        FileOutputCommitter committer = 
            (FileOutputCommitter) getOutputCommitter(context);
          return new Path(committer.getWorkPath(), "my-file-name.txt");
    }
}
```